# How does radiation (heat) take away momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, friction

In another post, I was taught that when we are moving (running, for example), radiation (in the form of heat, both from our muscles and friction with the ground) takes away from our momentum. That makes perfect sense and I understand.

I was also taught that heat/radiation is **directional**.

My question is: since radiation is directional, is that **why** it takes away from momentum (which is also directional)? Is it correct to say that? In other words, does radiation take away from momentum **because they are both directional** concepts?

Also, does radiation, since it is directional, dissipate in the **same** direction of momentum, in the **opposite** direction, or no particular direction?

I am not an expert, hoping just for simple clarification, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radiation will not "know" that it is being emitted by a uniformly moving body, so from the prespective of the body it will be emitted uniformly in all directions.  Momentum will be lost to the body to a *very* small degree, though, because the mass of the body will be reduced by a *very* small degree due to energy/mass equivalence.  However, the body will not change its velocity- only its mass and therefore its momentum.  In practice, the change is too small to observe.

Comment: Your reasoning is only valid if  the radiation is emitted equally in all directions, this is an important detail in this context

Comment: True, but no basis was given to expect that there would be a preferred direction for emission.  No specification of shape, composition, pattern of paint on the surface, etc.; so I default to uniform spherical object.

Comment: Really nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that we have a lone body moving freely across space, his momentum then is **conserved**, it has to stay the same through time. This derives directly from the laws of dynamic. End of the story. But  if the body emits radiation then some of the momentum of the body can be stolen by the photons that it emits, in fact photons carry momentum. But as long as the radiation is emitted in the same way in every direction, the momentum has to be conserved. In fact if the radiation is emitted in the same way in every direction any momentum given in one direction will be compensated by the photon emitted in the opposite direction. If the radiation is not emitted equally then you can have a sort of jet effect and the momentum of the body could indeed vary.

It can be tempting to state: since the body emits photons and the photons carry momentum, then the body must lose some momentum, because it gave it to the photons. Unfortunately this intuitive line of reasoning is wrong: we have to remember that momentum is not a scalar quantity but a vectorial one, so two particle with momentum equal in module but opposite in direction amount to a total of zero momentum.